# JSF - How to update the <h:selectOneMenu> value from the backing bean

Tags: jakarta-ee, jsf-2, selectonemenu, backing-beans

Here is my code for the `<h:selectOneMenu>`.
I am trying to update its value from the backing bean after assigning the value in backing bean execdirectorRC="XXXvalue".
Here,the `executivedirectorslist` does have a list values.

Here is the code in the form

```
<h:form id="ipdpform">
  <h:selectOneMenu id="exedirectors" value="#{Bean.execdirectorRC}">
    <f:selectItems value="#{Bean.executivedirectorslist}"
       var="s" itemLabel="#{s.label}" itemValue="#{s.value}" />
    <p:ajax listener="#{Bean.getDirectReporters}"
       update="rpt2 :growl :error" execute="@this"
       partialSubmit="true" />
    <f:param name="rpt1" value="rpt1" />
  </h:selectOneMenu>
</h:form >
```

Here is the code I am trying to udpate the value from the backing bean

```
RequestContext context = RequestContext.getCurrentInstance();
                execdirectorRC = "XXX,Name";
                context.update("ipdpform:exedirectors");
```

My problem is the value "XXX,Name"  is not getting udpated in the `<h:selectOneMenu>.` and the values is already available in the `Bean.executivedirectorslist`.How can i update it from backing bean ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use static utility functions like below.

```
public static void addWillBeUpdatedComponent(final String componentId) {
        FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getPartialViewContext()
                .getRenderIds().add(componentId);
    }

public static void removeWillBeUpdatedComponent(final String componentId) {
        FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getPartialViewContext()
                .getRenderIds().remove(componentId);
}
```

`componentId` must be in this format `form:componentId` not `:form:componentId`.

Comment: Thanks erk.But is there any way other than the above method like the one I have mentioned ?context.update("ipdpform:exedirectors"); ?

Comment: Thanks erk.But doesn't the code work in this way ?RequestContext context = RequestContext.getCurrentInstance();
                execdirectorRC = "XXX,Name";
                context.update("ipdpform:exedirectors");